# Callback of setTimeout function when performing synchronous actions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

Inside a function I'm calling playgame service. Once I've obtained the needed data (`gameBeingPlayed`), I need to show a 3..2..1 counter and then start a game.

```
chooseGameService.playGame(gameDefinitionID)
                .then(function () {

                    vm.container.gameBeingPlayed = chooseGameService.gameBeingPlayed;

                    showGame();

                    counter(3);  

                });
```

```
 function counter(count) {
        vm.container.counterVisible = true;

        var countDownFrom = count;
        var timer = setInterval(function() { handleTimer(count); }, 1000);

        function handleTimer() {
            if(count === 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                //
                initGame();
                vm.container.counterVisible = false;
            } else {
                $('#gameCount').text(count);
                count--;
            }
        }           
    }
```

The things that bothers me is that I had to move the next two lines from the service (promise) callback to the counter in order to execute the code synchronously.

```
initGame();
vm.container.counterVisible = false;
```

It works, but it seems semantically wrong for me that `initGame()` and visibility change is inside the counter function instead of inside the callback of the service (which is inside the controller).

Is there any way I could keep these lines inside the `.then()` of the controller instead of inside the counter function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make the `counter` function return a promise. If you understand promises, I think this example will be enough. If not, please ask and I'll clarify.

```
function counter(count) {
    var deferred = Promise.defer();

    var countDownFrom = count;
    var timer = setInterval(function() { handleTimer(countDownFrom); }, 1000);

    function handleTimer(count) {
        if (count === 0) {
            clearInterval(timer);
            deferred.resolve();
        } else {
            console.log(count);
            countDownFrom--;
        }
    }

    return deferred.promise;
}

Promise.resolve()
    .then(function() {
        console.log('start');
        return counter(3);
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('ready');
    });
```